# Applying inference rules for 2 liars and a truth teller

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

This is the scenario. "you meet three people, alice, bob, and carol. You need to decide which ones are liars and which ones are truth tellers based on the following conversation.

you ask alice: "are you a liar?"

Before Alice gets a chance to answer, Bob interrupts: “You can always trust Alice! She is telling the truth!

Carol exclaims, “Don’t believe Bob! He’s lying!”

Carol then adds “Also, Alice is a liar.”

Finally, Alice gets a chance to speak: “Don’t believe anything you’ve heard! They are
both liars!

Lets say Carol = C, alice = A and bob = B.

I came to the conclusion that

B ⇐⇒ A and
C ⇐⇒ ¬B and
C ⇐⇒ ¬A and
A ⇐⇒ ¬B ∧¬C

Based of this I know that the liars are A and B while C is telling the truth. My question is, how do I use inference rules to prove this?

Comment: $A\iff (\lnot B\land \lnot C)$; $B\iff A$ so $B\iff (\lnot B \land \lnot C)$.  $\lnot B\lnot C\implies -\lnot B$ so $B\implies \lnot B$ so $\lnot B$.  $B \iff A$ so $\lnot A$.  $C\iff \lnot A$ and $\lnot A$ so $C$.

Comment: @fleablood Why not post as an answer